# Getting sequential logs while executing tests in parallel

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, integration-testing

We have been using `testng` with `java` to execute integration tests for our code. We have implemented a ***listener*** for the test execution as follows :-

```
public class TestExecutionListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod iInvokedMethod, ITestResult iTestResult) {
        System.out.println("Testing : " + iInvokedMethod.getTestMethod().getMethodName());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod iInvokedMethod, ITestResult iTestResult) {
        System.out.println("Successfully Tested : " + iInvokedMethod.getTestMethod().getMethodName());
    }
}
```

Our ***testng.xml*** is defined as :-

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="TestSuite" verbose="1" parallel="classes" thread-count="10">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="core.TestExecutionListener"/>
    </listeners>

    <test name="IntegrationTests">
        <classes>
            <class name="test.SomeTest1"/>
            <class name="test.SomeTest2"/>
            <class name="test.SomeTest3"/>
            <class name="test.SomeTest4"/>
            ... There are more than 20 classes
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

As we execute the tests, the output that we get is as follows :

> ```
> Testing : SomeTest1Method1
> Testing : SomeTest2Method2
> Testing : SomeTest4Method5
> Successfully Tested : SomeTest2Method2
> Successfully Tested : SomeTest4Method5
> ```

while what we would be expecting the output to be is:-

> ```
> Testing : SomeTest1Method1
> Successfully Tested : SomeTest1Method1
> Testing : SomeTest2Method2
> Successfully Tested : SomeTest2Method2
> Testing : SomeTest4Method5
> Successfully Tested : SomeTest4Method5
> ```

Guessing this to because of the `parallel="classes"` attribute in the xml, since changing it to `false` provides the desired output. But as obvious the changed execution consumes a lot more time as compared to parallel execution.

***Is there a way to run these tests in parallel but still get this output in sequence?***

Comment: Log to different loggers then output in an AfterAll block?

Comment: @PaulHicks - further hints on that please. Couldn't get the part of logging to different loggers.

Comment: Use a logging utility like log4j. Get a logger from it using something specific to your test (you've got the IInvokedMethod interface which will suffice; there may be something more suitable). Log to it, instead of using `System.out`. Optionally at the end, read from all loggers and concatenate to `System.out`.

Comment: @PaulHicks - Would try using log4j, doubt a strong component to differentiate the tests for the log4j appenders.(looking for using IInvokedMethod interface if feasible.)

Comment: You could use `IInvokedMethod#getTestMethod().getInstance().getClass().getName()` as the name of the logger. That should work.

Comment: Have you considered post-processing? Let events get into the log in the order in which they actually happened. Include a transaction number or similar in each message. Write a script to group them by transact number in order of first appearance of the transaction number.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - post processing as suggested seems to be more complex. Like adding transaction number to each message doesn't really makes sense. Also probably running a script post logging would give me the results quite late. What if I am looking for these logs at the runtime as well?

Comment: @PaulHicks - trying your suggested way, wouldn't I end up having a logger for every unique name e.g  for each class? and then merging these all log files data into one is not what I am seeking.

Comment: Yes, you could. Or you could get the logger per namespace, or something else. But if all those loggers are associated with a single appender, then the log utility will do the merging for you. Plus you have the option of having different appenders for (e.g.) debugging, experiments, new classes, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enable parallel then there will be some time between the `beforeInvocation` and `afterInvocation` in the logs as you have noticed and that difference in time varies from test to test hence the staggered output.

If what you want is the start and end messages next to each other then you are basically throwing out the time factor and as such can simply add your `beforeInvocation` message to the `afterInvocation` method as follows:

```
public class TestExecutionListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod iInvokedMethod, ITestResult iTestResult) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod iInvokedMethod, ITestResult iTestResult) {
        System.out.println("Testing : " + iInvokedMethod.getTestMethod().getMethodName());
        System.out.println("Successfully Tested : " + iInvokedMethod.getTestMethod().getMethodName());
    }
}
```

IMO this is the only way to do it as per your spec.  However, if there is other information that must be gathered during the tests then perhaps you could buffer some logs in the `TestExecutionListener` for example:

```
public class TestExecutionListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {
    private Map<Integer, Deque<String>> logsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Deque<String>>();

    public void log(IInvokedMethod iInvokedMethod, String log) {
        if(!logsMap.containsKey(iInvokedMethod.getId())) {
            logsMap.put(iInvokedMethod.getId(), new ArrayDeque<String>());
        }

        logsMap.get(iInvokedMethod.getId()).add(log);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod iInvokedMethod, ITestResult iTestResult) {
        log(iInvokedMethod, "Testing : " + iInvokedMethod.getTestMethod().getMethodName());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod iInvokedMethod, ITestResult iTestResult) {
        log(iInvokedMethod, "Successfully Tested : " + iInvokedMethod.getTestMethod().getMethodName());

        Deque<String> logs = logsMap.get(iInvokedMethod.getId());
        while(!logs.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(logs.poll());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost thing I would recommend you to use log4j or similar logger tools, which is elegant, modular & provides lot of flexible options. This also lays down the path to design & handle logging mechanism in multiple ways.

If you have a business requirement, which needs you to track the logs of each thread separately, you should consider streaming of this logs to different files. Log4j kind of tools do support the requirement of writing to multiple files. You can just do google search, you will get lot information.

Comment: Reiterating from question - "The problem statement is descriptive enough. Just to clear - Looking for a more appropriate solution to what has already been mentioned in the comments section over logging in different loggers and then merging the logs"